# The compiler implicitly declares a default constructor

Tags: c++, destructor

I am reading textbook "C++ Primer Plus, Prata"

A paragraph in chapter 10 catches my eye and confuses me.

Ch.10 Objects and classes:

[image]

It says

> If you don't provide ***one***, the compiler implicitly declares a default **constructor** and,...

I thought it should be

> If you don't provide ***destructor***, the compiler implicitly declares a default **destructor** and,...

Is the paragraph correct?

How should I explain that correctly?

Thank you

Comment: Yes, it's a printing error. If you don't provide a destructor, the compiler declares a destructor for you.

Comment: No wonder that book [gets bad reviews](http://accu.org/index.php?module=bookreviews&func=search&rid=1744).

Comment: For the record: Before the edits I didn't see the image and only saw the quotes. My answer was thus somewhat confusing and I deleted it.

Comment: I heard people badmouthing C++ Primer Plus

Comment: I know it got bad reviews from some people. But this textbook has got 4 out of 5 stars on Amazon. There are still other people praising this one. Though I don't know why..

Comment: @Yam Marcovic  I read your answer and I know what you mean. Still thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "one" part is correct. That's just a nuance of English grammar where you can refer to something in a dependent clause that comes later in the sentence. Think of it like a forward declaration! The "default constructor" part is actually a typo: it should be "default destructor", like you originally thought.

It should say this:

> Because a destructor is called automatically when a class object expires, there ought to be a destructor. If you don't provide one [a destructor], the compiler implicitly declares a default destructor and, if it detects code that leads to the destruction of an object, it provides a definition for the destructor.

Here, "one" refers to "a destructor," which comes later in the sentence. Another key to understanding the sentence is keeping in mind the distinction between *declaring* a function and *defining* a function. The compiler always *declares* an implicit destructor if you don't provide one, but it only *defines* it if it needs it (that is, if that destructor is going to be called).

What makes it all the more confusing (and probably what led to the typo) is that all of this is equally true for constructors.

Let's see if we can improve on the paragraph:

> Because the destructor will be called automatically when a class object goes out of scope, all classes must have a destructor. If you don't explicitly provide one, the compiler implicitly declares a default destructor. If the compiler detects code that leads to the destruction of an object, it *also* provides a default definition for the destructor. The same thing is true for constructors.

Comment: As a student majoring in mathematics, it is common to spot typos in textbooks on mathematics, but I am not familiar with programming. so reading a paragraph like this one made me a little worried. Your explanation is more clear. Thanks